# HTTP Post works but GET doesnt work

Tags: java, parse-platform

I am using parse.com's REST API for my login system (API: https://parse.com/docs/rest#users-signup ).

The problem is while register works:

```
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("username", username);
    json.put("password", password);
    json.put("email", email);
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Reference.PARSE_API_URL
            + Reference.PARSE_API_USERS);
    httppost.addHeader("X-Parse-Application-Id", Reference.APP_ID);
    httppost.addHeader("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", Reference.REST_API_KEY);
    httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(json.toString()));
    HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    System.out.println(httpresponse.getStatusLine());
```

The login system doesnt (yes i encrypt the data as the site says):

```
            JSONObject jsonadd = new JSONObject();
        jsonadd.put("username", username);
        jsonadd.put("password", password);

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(Reference.PARSE_API_URL + Reference.PARSE_API_LOGIN + "?" + URLEncoder.encode(jsonadd.toString(), "UTF-8"));
        httpget.addHeader("X-Parse-Application-Id", Reference.APP_ID);
        httpget.addHeader("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", Reference.REST_API_KEY);
        HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        System.out.println(httpresponse.getStatusLine());
```

And these are the reference variables:

```
    public static final String APP_ID = "(HIDDEN)";
public static final String REST_API_KEY = (HIDDEN)";

public static final String VERSION_CLASS_NAME = "version";

public static final String PARSE_API_URL = "https://api.parse.com";
public static final String PARSE_API_URL_CLASSES = "/1/classes/";
public static final String PARSE_API_USERS = "/1/users";
public static final String PARSE_API_LOGIN = "/1/login";
```

The error:
   HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Answer (score 1):

Ansering my own question:

The data doesnt need to be encoded,
the connection needs to be

```
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://api.parse.com/1/login?username="username"&password="password"");
```

(without quotations at the usernme and password